# Pandas Dataframe save to CSV alters list of times

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

PLease refer to the picture and help out, I cant seem to solve the issue through casting, is it an encoding issue? 
  [image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

To get similar format as in jupyter use format the dates before exporting

```
df['Times'] = df['Times'].apply(lambda x: [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in x])
```

Comment: its a list of dates actually

Comment: oh, my bad...then user strftime() function on all items in lists before exporting